# Left join, Union All and INTO OUTFILE syntax error mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to export a query containing a left join to a csv file with columns name. The problem is in the syntax, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
SELECT 'Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Date'
UNION ALL  
SELECT 
    (users.name, users.email, IF(trip.active, 'SI', 'NO') as active, trip.updated_at AS fecha)
    INTO OUTFILE 'route' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    FROM users LEFT JOIN trip ON users.id = trip.user_id
```

Comment: Please write query like that SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'data1'... UNION select column FROM table 1 left join table2) t INTO INTO OUTFILE 'route' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

Comment: Thank you, it is working. How would I add an order by to the query you proposed ?

Comment: I think data1, data2 ... is worked as header so you need to order by in second query. please check this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b40d77ace74586f56f58bec4c1adf992

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but I do not understand, the example is not similar to the one you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put parentheses around the `SELECT` list.

```
SELECT 'Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Date'
UNION ALL  
SELECT 
    users.name, users.email, IF(trip.active, 'SI', 'NO') as active, trip.updated_at AS fecha
INTO OUTFILE 'route' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN trip ON users.id = trip.user_id
```

Comment: did not work for me
#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near 'FROM users LEFT JOIN trip ON users.id = trip.user_id' on line 6

Comment: I can't reproduce that error.

Comment: Check the line before `FROM` to make sure you don't have a typo there.

Comment: If I take out the INTO OUTFILE line it works. I can't understand the error, it's a syntax error but I can't find the problem.

Comment: I did it with `INTO OUTFILE` and it worked for me.

Comment: I executed this exact command, and didn't get a syntax error. I got a different error because I don't have tables with these names, but that happens after it decides the syntax is OK.